# Leer un archivo .csv dentro de una carpeta en pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Mi archivo .py esta fuera de una carpeta. Deseo leer un archivo. csv que esta dentro de una carpeta.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./Campbell 1/CR3000-Mangrove2_Table1.csv")
```

Deseo saber la forma correcta de poder leer un archivo .csv con pandas desde fuera de una carpeta.

Un dato a tener en cuenta es que no se si el espacio que hay entre **Campbell** y el numero **1** influya a la hora de buscar la ruta.

Comment: ¿`Campbell 1` esta en la misma carpeta que el script?

Comment: Si, la Campbell 1 se encuentra en la misma carpeta del Script

Comment: @Mike prueba usando la ruta completa del archivo

Comment: Mike ¿tienes alguna excepción? si es así agregala. El código es en principio correcto, pero las rutas relativas al ejecutar en consolas dedicadas en ciertos ides pueden fallar porque cambian el directorio de trabajo. ¿Si ejecutas el script desde la propia terminal/CMD tienes problemas?

Comment: Me sirvió colocando la ruta completa, gracias @eyllanesc, aunque me queda la duda de porque no me sale con la ruta relativa.

Comment: Si @FJSevilla todos mis programas los ejecuto en consola, solo utilizo el editor de texto para programar. En este caso uso Visual Studio Code pero no tiene nada que ver ya que lo ejecuto en consola

Answer (score 1):

La ruta del archivo es tomado en referencia a donde ejecutaste tu script, en tu caso la ruta de la consola.

Siempre es recomendable la ruta absoluta de cualquier recurso, pero por portabilidad ni se debe usar la ruta explicitamente sino construirlo.

En este caso se dede usar `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` que devolvera el nombre del directorio del archivo .py.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 
filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "Campbell 1/CR3000-Mangrove2_Table1.csv") 
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```